# Write NDEF message inside a loop

Tags: android, while-loop, nfc, message, ndef

I want to write different NDEF messages inside a while() loop.

LAST EDIT: It seems that the microcontroller can't process data so fast, so my problem cannot be solved.

```
//ndef.connect();
ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
//ndef.close();
```

My write() method, simplified, without all try/catch

So, at first loop it works correctly, but next ones don't. But after a number of loops it works again for one more time. This repeats.

```
stop = 0;    
while(stop < 1000)
    {
        write();
        stop++
    }
```

write() is working correctly for one loop.

EDIT: I replaced while() with a timer:

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
               write();
                }
}, 2000);
```

But this is too slow... I need to write at least 5 times per second. 
If I set timer period less than 2000 it doesn't work, works same as while()

EDIT2: I measured how fast a message is transmitted and received. It seems it takes about 55ms to send a message, and about 7ms to receive. This is what I want, but if I set my timer to repeat after 100ms, for example, I have this error from `writeNDEFmessage()` :
`java.io.IOException: Tag is not ndef` . So if I loop 10 times `writeNDEFmessage()` it works fine at first loop but I receive exception at the following 9.

EDIT3:

`onNewIntent()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) ||
                    intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)||
                    intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED))
            {
                detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

                if(detectedTag != lastDetectedTag)
                {

                    lastDetectedTag = detectedTag;
                    setIntent(intent);
                }


            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("", "onIntent >>> "+e.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

This is assigned to a button:

```
 public void testWrite()
    {

        final Timer timer = new Timer();

        try {
            ndef = Ndef.get(detectedTag);
            ndef.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", "Cannot connect");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                transmit.writeTag(message), ndef) 

        }, 0, 200);

    }
```

and `writeTag()`:

```
public boolean writeTag(String str, Ndef ndef) {


        try {
            message = getNdefMessage(str);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           toast("Message error");
        }

        int size = message.toByteArray().length;

        try {


            if (ndef != null) {

                if(!ndef.isConnected())
                {
                    ndef.connect();
                    Log.e("", ""+ndef.toString());
                }

                if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size) {
                    toast("Tag capacity is " + ndef.getMaxSize() + " bytes, message is " + size + " bytes.");
                    return false;
                }
                try{

                    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    toast("error send");
                    Log.e("IOException", e + "-+-");
                    return false;
                }


                return true;
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            toast("Failed to write tag");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

`transmit` is an object from `Transmit` class, in which `writeTag()` is defined

`onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        transmit = new Transmit(this);
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        textView.setText("");
        detectedTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        lastDetectedTag = detectedTag;
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass()).
                        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        IntentFilter filter2     = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        readTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected,filter2};
        techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };


        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC

            finish();
            return;

        }

        if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {

        }


        buttonListener(testButton);

    }
```

Comment: What android version and phone are you testing with?

Comment: Android 4.4.2, API19, Motorola RAZR HD

Comment: Is the `ndef.connect{}` and `ndef.close()` part required? It might me done outside the "loop". I wonder why are you doing that sort of stress testing? There might be a different way to achieve your "goal".

Comment: Removed `ndef.connect()` and `ndef.close()` from loop.  Same...

Comment: Added more info  @vlp

Comment: According to the NDEF class docs the writeNdefMessage() "It must not be called from the main application thread." so definitely drop the runOnUiThread. Are you writing in an AsyncTask? And the most important question: What type of tag are you using?

Comment: What about synchronized(ndef) {ndef.writeNdefMessage(message); } inside write()? Additional ndef.isWritable() might reveal something. Where is the write re-scheduled? Your code setups just a single execution. Dropping runOnUiThread() is a good advice. What is the purpose a repeatedly rewritting the ndef on a tag? Benchmark?

Comment: @vlp I removed it from `runOnUiThread()`. In debugger i added a breakpoint in `onNewIntent` and it's reaching it every 4-5 loops, also `isConnected()` returns false for 4-5 loops

Comment: @jgriffin didn't think about that, `detectedtag.toString()` returns `TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.Ndef]`

Comment: @jgriffin OP edited to add more details, hope this helps

Comment: Did you try to use the NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()/disableForegroundDispatch()? This _might_ help. Do you receive those mentioned spurious onNewIntent() calls even if you do not call the testWriteTag() at all? Sometimes looking into the logcat helps a lot -- look especially for Nfc, Tag, Ndef...I have no more ideas :(

Comment: yes, I use `NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()/disableForegroundDispatch()` I receive `onNewIntent` after every loop...

Comment: But you shouldn't receive a new Intent after every loop? You should only receive a new intent when the tag enters the phone's field. I thought you were leaving the phone on the tag and writing in a loop so as to ascertain performance? Please explain how you are performing the test and what exactly you are trying to measure.

Comment: I put my phone over a microcontroller and press the button that starts to write my messages. After every write, the microcontroller sends me an answer. Both send and receive are working correctly without loop. The phone doesn't move from microcontroller all this time so the tag is always in range. But, after every write I hear a small sound from the microcontroller. @jgriffin

Comment: What tag are you using?

Comment: @jgriffin Type 4 Tag  ISO/IEC 14443

Answer (score 2):

From the `Ndef` docs for the `close()` method: "Disable I/O operations to the tag from this TagTechnology object, and release resources."

So I think when you call `close()` the internal `TagTechnology` is released. If you call connect on the same ndef it's a "stale" object. Try creating a new `Ndef` object each time by passing it the Tag object.

Edit: Or else just don't call `close()` until you're actually finished. You will still need to call `connect()` the first time. Additionally I'd always call `isConnected()` first to ensure the tag is present and connected.

Comment: removed `ndef.connect()` and `ndef.close()` from `write()` and added a `ndef.isConnected()` check. In debugger it reaches this every 4-5 loops with different values for ndef
`Ndef@4219b850
Ndef@42151838
Ndef@4210a068
etc`

Comment: Well from your comment above you mention you have a breakpoint in `onNewIntent()`. This will only be triggered when the tag leaves and re-enters the field. So trying to loop a write in another thread and waiting for a breakpoint in `onNewIntent()` does not make sense. Please post your full Activity class with all NFC logic intact so we can see where the problem might be.